# Counting unserialized array grouped by index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a serialized array in my database that I have extracted and unserialized. It has a structure like this:

```
array (
  526744 => 
  array (
    'completed' => 13,
    'total' => 24,
    'topics' => 
    array (
    ),
    'lessons' => 
    array (
      526745 => 1,
      526747 => 1,
      526749 => 1,
      526751 => 0,
      526753 => 0,
      526755 => 0,
      526757 => 0,
      526759 => 0,
      526761 => 1,
    ),
    'last_id' => 526793,
  )
```

The first number is a course id (there are actually 3 courses I've just included the first here).

I have pulled this out of the database for several different users, so I have the above several times over.

I am trying to count the lessons, so that I know how many users have passed each lesson.

I have the following code:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $course_progress = unserialize($result->course_progress);
    $lesson_progress = $course_progress[$course_id][lessons];
    print_r(array_count_values($lesson_progress));
}
```

This outputs this:

```
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 11 [0] => 13 ) 
Array ( [1] => 13 [0] => 11 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 23 [0] => 1 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 21 [0] => 3 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [1] => 24 ) 
Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 3 )
```

This is obviously completely wrong. But I cannot think of how to get it to work. I think the issue is that I have a separate array for each user with my current code maybe?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So are you counting the lessons passed per user? Or do you want a count of users passed per lesson?

Comment: I'm trying to get a count of users passed per lesson.

Comment: And the object you shared (first code snippet) is a course listing of a specific user? Or a total per course listing?

Comment: Swap `array_count_values` to `array_sum`

Comment: That is of a specific user. the foreach($results as $result) will output that for every user in a group (if i were to print_r it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 4:

```
$users = array(
    'john' => array(
        526744 => array (
            'completed' => 13,
            'total' => 24,
            'topics' =>
                array (),
            'lessons' =>
                array (
                    526745 => 1,
                    526747 => 1,
                    526749 => 1,
                    526751 => 0,
                    526753 => 0,
                    526755 => 0,
                    526757 => 0,
                    526759 => 0,
                    526761 => 1,
                ),
            'last_id' => 526793,
        ),
        526745 => array (
            'completed' => 13,
            'total' => 24,
            'topics' =>
                array (),
            'lessons' =>
                array (
                    526745 => 1,
                    526747 => 1,
                    526749 => 1,
                    526751 => 0,
                    526753 => 1,
                    526755 => 0,
                    526757 => 0,
                    526759 => 0,
                    526761 => 1,
                ),
            'last_id' => 526793,
        ),
    ),
        'joe' => array(
            526744 => array (
                'completed' => 13,
                'total' => 24,
                'topics' =>
                    array (),
                'lessons' =>
                    array (
                        526745 => 1,
                        526747 => 1,
                        526749 => 1,
                        526751 => 0,
                        526753 => 0,
                        526755 => 0,
                        526757 => 0,
                        526759 => 0,
                        526761 => 1,
                    ),
                'last_id' => 526793,
            ),
            526745 => array (
                'completed' => 13,
                'total' => 24,
                'topics' =>
                    array (),
                'lessons' =>
                    array (
                        526745 => 1,
                        526747 => 1,
                        526749 => 1,
                        526751 => 1,
                        526753 => 1,
                        526755 => 0,
                        526757 => 0,
                        526759 => 0,
                        526761 => 1,
                    ),
                'last_id' => 526793,
            ),
    )
);
$counts = [];
foreach($users as $userId => $userCourses){
    foreach($userCourses as $courseId => $course){
        foreach($course['lessons'] as $lessonId => $lesson){
            $counts[$courseId][$lessonId] = empty($counts[$courseId][$lessonId]) ? $lesson : $counts[$courseId][$lessonId]+$lesson;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($counts);
```

Obviously My array keys (john and joe) are just for testing purposes so the outermost foreach is negligible.

Returns:

```
array (size=2)
  526744 => 
    array (size=9)
      526745 => int 2
      526747 => int 2
      526749 => int 2
      526751 => int 0
      526753 => int 0
      526755 => int 0
      526757 => int 0
      526759 => int 0
      526761 => int 2
  526745 => 
    array (size=9)
      526745 => int 2
      526747 => int 2
      526749 => int 2
      526751 => int 1
      526753 => int 2
      526755 => int 0
      526757 => int 0
      526759 => int 0
      526761 => int 2
```

Comment: Slightly misunderstood. The top level of each array (e.g. 526744) is actually a course, not a user. I am filtering it down to the one specific course in the code I show above. The original query I submit returns the seperate array for each user.

Comment: So in your example, you're expecting to see 4? As the user is following/passed 4 lessons in that course?

Comment: Well I would expect to see the id of each lesson with a 1 next to it, but as it loops through all the users, each lesson would increase for every student that has passed.

Comment: This is so close I can taste it. Basically there is still a small misunderstanding. In the array in your example you have two different courses with matching lessons. I actually have different lessons in each course but obviously several users to add up from. I merged the arrays produced for each user using array_merge and ran your code and it does work, but it is adding up every lesson for every course. I just need to specify it to only add up lessons from a single course.